# simple java calculator errors

Tags: java, calculator

Hi i recently took an interest into java 2 days ago, and while watching some tutorials, i decided to make a calculator after seeing a super simple addition calc example done. i was wondering where did i turn wrong. plz help im super new to it.(also im using eclipse idk if that makes a difference)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;
    int problem = multiplication, division, addition, subtraction;
    int answer = answerM, answerD, answerA, answerS;


    System.out.println("enter first number: "); 
    x = number.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter operator: "); 
    signs(); = operation.nextInt();     
    System.out.println("enter second number: ");
    y = number.nextInt();
    System.out.println(answer); 


    if (problem == signs()){
        answerM = x * y;
    }else{
        if (problem = signs()){
            answerD = x / y;
        }else{
            if (problem == signs()){
                answerA = x + y;
            }else{
                if (problem == signs()){
                    answerS = x - y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private static int signs() {
    multiplication = "*";
    division = "/";
    addition = "+";
    subtraction = "-";
    return 0;
}
}
```

errors,errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    multiplication cannot be resolved to a variable
    answerM cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on token "=", delete this token
    answerM cannot be resolved to a variable
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

    at calculator.main(calculator.java:10)
```

Comment: Please spend some time reading the language reference before setting off to write a calculator.  Statements like `int problem = multiplication, division, addition, subtraction;` indicate that you _need_ some _bit_ of reading.

Comment: @devnull, it would work, if there was a `multiplication` previously declared ;)

Comment: There are so many problems. Start learning from the docs or buy a good book.

Comment: _"while watching some tutorials"_. I would recommend reading some books. YouTube tutorials leave a lot of detail out.

Comment: Great Java textbook "Introduction to Java Programming" by Daniel Liang. I believe most recent edition is 9th :)

Comment: Watching tutorials for 2 days and resolving doubts on SO is not the best way to learn Java. As devnull suggested, please spend some time reading good books. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks ill make sure to buy a book.  Is java for dummies ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code.. This is working fine.  Check your errors and see the solutions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // no need of two Scanners to read the same stream
    //   Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
    //  Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    int y;
    // can't declare variables like this in java
    //        int problem = multiplication, division, addition, subtraction;
    //        int answer = answerM, answerD, answerA, answerS;
    int answer = 0;

    System.out.println("enter first number: ");
    x = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter operator: ");
    // you can't assign a value to a method call
    //signs(); = operation.nextInt();
    String sign = input.next();
    System.out.println("enter second number: ");
    y = input.nextInt();
    //        System.out.println(answer);


   //        if (problem == signs()) {
   //            answerM = x * y;
   //        } else {
   //            if (problem = signs()) {
  //                answerD = x / y;
  //            } else {
  //                if (problem == signs()) {
  //                    answerA = x + y;
  //                } else {
  //                    if (problem == signs()) {
  //                        answerS = x - y;
  //                    }
  //                }
  //            }
  //        }
    if (sign.equals("*")) {
        answer = x * y;
    } else {
        if (sign.equals("/")) {
            answer = x / y;
        } else {
            if (sign.equals("+")) {
                answer = x + y;
            } else {
                if (sign.equals("-")) {
                    answer = x - y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer);

}
   //This method  always return '0'
  //    private static int signs() {
  //        multiplication = "*";
  //        division = "/";
  //        addition = "+";
  //        subtraction = "-";
  //        return 0;
  //    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for analyzing and explaining each part

Comment: For the int x and int y,  should it be public int x; and public int y;

Comment: they are inside a method. (int main method) so they only visible in that method. No point making them public. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129855/java-never-declares-access-level-of-variables-in-methods-whether-static-or-not) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in these lines

```
signs(); = operation.nextInt();
```

```
if (problem = signs()){
```

it will assign return value of `signs()` to the variable `problem`.

You can better to use `equals()` ie `problem.equals(signs())`

Comment: Cool thank you.  Ill try that, and reading a bit more on java before rushing in like this.

Comment: @user3097986 ok Gud...Keep Going   :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

```
int problem = multiplication, division, addition, subtraction;
```

**Problem 2**

```
int answer = answerM, answerD, answerA, answerS;
```

**Problem 3**

```
signs(); = operation.nextInt();
```

**Things to remember:**

```
private static int signs() {
    multiplication = "*";
    division = "/";
    addition = "+";
    subtraction = "-";
    return 0;
}
```

this shows that multiplication, division, addition  are strings nad you wrote

```
int problem = multiplication, division, addition, subtraction;
```

- `problem` is int and `multiplication` is string so this conversion is not possible.
- This method return type is int and it always return 0 so what is the need of return type as int. it must be void(this is not the problem but for best practice)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to these two lines:

```
int problem = multiplication, division, addition, subtraction;
int answer = answerM, answerD, answerA, answerS;
```

You have declared `int problem = multiplication`, but multiplication is not defined anywhere.
Similarly, in the declaration `int answer = answerM` is not defined.

You can remove these errors by declaring these two int variables:

```
int answerM = 0;
int multiplication = 0;
```

Comment: Oh ok,  i see where i went wrong on that part.  Thanks man,  ill make sure to change it.